# E00001:invalid syntax in vscode when trying to pull text from files

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to make a twitter bot that posts updates mentioning other accounts whose handles are text documents in a folder inside of the root folder the python script is in. VSCode, however, keeps flagging line 19 with an invalid syntax error (E00001). I'm using the tweepy and os modules.

```
 os.chdir('accounts')
    for name in os.listdir('.'):
        acct = open.(name, 'r') #line 19
        api.update_status('@' + acct + ' message')
```

Comment: You have a `.` between `open` and `(name, 'r')`. I believe this is your error.

Comment: Ok, this got rid of the syntax error in VSCode, but now whenever I run the code in python, I get a

    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'accounts'

That's definitely the name of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 issues:

1. You have a `.` between `open` and `(name, 'r')`. This causes a Syntax Error.
2. [`os.chdir()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chdir.htm) requires an absolute path. Plus, `accounts` is not a directory; `/accounts` is a directory. You'll need to do something like the following:

   ```
   path = '/accounts'

   # this changes to the directory given by the  absolute path appended with your directory
   os.chdir(os.getcwd() + path) 
   for name in os.listdir('.'):
       acct = open.(name, 'r') #line 19
       api.update_status('@' + acct + ' message')
   ```